# Cordova iOS file read error: "Failed to load resource: You do not have permission to access the requested resource."

Tags: ios, file, cordova

I have download one zip file and extracted at **cordova.file.dataDirectory/templates/**. And I have accessed it by the same path, but it shows **"Failed to load resource: You do not have permission to access the requested resource."**.
Please see below screenshot - 
[image]

Previously it was working well in iOS and Android. But now it showing this issue in iOS only.
I googled it but didn't get any solution, Please help me, guys.